# feColorMatrix not working on Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am facing something weird on Firefox. I'm trying to set a SVG icon color, and it works perfectly on Chrome and Opera, but not on **Firefox**. There are no errors as well, so I don't know what is happening.

Here is my code =>

```js
const svg_object = document.createElement('object');
svg_object.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml');
svg_object.setAttribute('width', '25px');
svg_object.setAttribute('height', '25px');
svg_object.setAttribute('data', 'https://www.svgrepo.com/show/38250/whatsapp.svg');
svg_object.setAttribute('class', 'obj');
document.body.appendChild(svg_object);

const filter = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'filter');
filter.id = 'myFilter'
const filter_color = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'feColorMatrix');
filter_color.setAttribute('type', 'matrix');
filter_color.setAttribute('values', '0 0 0 0 0.9686274509803922 0 0 0 0 0.8235294117647058 0 0 0 0 0.5490196078431373 0 0 0 1 0');
filter.appendChild(filter_color);
document.body.appendChild(filter);

svg_object.style.filter = 'url(#myFilter)';
```

(Not working only on FIREFOX browser (latest version))

Do you know why this is happening? As far I know, Firefox supports `filter` element

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

specify the namespace as follows.
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).